# Как можно передать функцию с возвращаемым значением в defer

Tags: функции, golang

Возникла потребность в модуле супервизоре, функция, которая засекает время выполнение работы другой функции, должна вернуть структуру со всеми полученным данными, то есть:

```
func tricktime(t time.Time) *Trick {//Trick структура с названием текущей функции, временем выполнении функции и т.д}
```

В `defer` это не пойдет так как зачем мне совать в `defer` функцию от которой я ничего не получу, так как не будет никакого возвратного значения... нужно было что-то типа `defer t := tricktime(time.Now())` но это нарушает все границы синтакса и работать это не будет, другое решение которое мне пришло в голову это было в качестве аргумента вернуть функцию, то есть `func tricktime(t time.Time) func() *Trick {}` внутри функции было что-то типа

```
_exist := func() *Trick {return *Trick{}}; return _exist
```

Тогда я мог сделать вот так:

```
func Some() string {
    tt := tricktime(time.Now()); defer tt()
    newTt:= tt(); 
    fmt.Println(newTt.Data) // Обязательное поле, данные должны быть получены. 
    return ""
}
```

Но это не работало в случае с засеканием времени, потому что функция `tt()` преждевременно завершала работу на самых первых наносекундах, потому что defer не работал. ***ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО НУЖНО ПОЛУЧИТЬ ВОЗВРАЩАЕМЫЙ АРГУМЕНТ ФУНКЦИИ КОТОРЫЙ ПРЕДСТАВЛЯЕТ СОБОЙ СТРУКТУРУ `*Trick` ВМЕСТЕ С defer***. Вот полный код:

```
func tricktime(t time.Time) *Trick {
    var tt Trick 
    tt.Start = t
    defer func() {tt.Elapsed = time.Now().Sub(t)}()

    var reStrip = regexp.MustCompile(`^.*\.(.*)$`)
    pc, _, _, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if ok {
        tt.Name = reStrip.ReplaceAllString(runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), "$1")
    }
    tt.End = time.Now()
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Нужно дать имена возвращаемым значениям, и в замыкании переданном `defer` присвоить им значения или изменить существующие эти значения.

```
func Work() (spent time.Duration) {
    var tp = time.Now()

    defer func() {
        spent = time.Now().Sub(tp)
    }()

    time.Sleep(123 * time.Microsecond)

    fmt.Println("work")
    return
}
```

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/AktYlj7wq2D).

Comment: Вы меня не поняли, мне не нужно вручную засовывать таймера на time.Sleep() и считать сколько пройдет секунд, у меня функция `tricktime` отдельно идет, она должна считать время выполнения других функций, а не время выполнения самой себя.

Comment: @youhavenopass, `time.Sleep` нужен для примера, чтобы не получить ноль.

Comment: @youhavenopass, рекомендую пройти [тур](https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/welcome/1), чтобы основы языка были понятны.

Comment: я это прекрасно понимаю, что time.Sleep для примера был дан, тур я давным давно прошел по второму кругу проходить смысла нету, но вы предоставили функцию в коде которая засекает время выполнения самой себя, а мне нужно "универсальная" функция которая засекает время выполнении другой функции

Comment: @youhavenopass, и кто мешает `defer func(tp time.Time){ spent = time.Now().Sub(tp) }(time.Now())`? Понять как работает `defer` Вам нужно, а не универсальную функцию. Не нравится `spent =` делайте лог, не имеет значения.

Comment: @youhavenopass, например [так](https://play.golang.org/p/Il7QcVrqFcZ), для любителей однострочных выражений.

Comment: опять 25.. я прекрасно знаю как работают все суперглобальные функции Golang и т.д, не первый месяц Golang изучаю.. Вы умеете читать до конца текст вопроса? Я уже капсом с подчеркиванием написал что мне нужно получить возвращаемый аргумент функции который является структурой *Trick .

Comment: @youhavenopass, простите, Вы этот код понимаете? Кто мешает пихнуть в `defer` этот `Trick` и там [обработать](https://play.golang.org/p/vzwZBN9QddV)?  Вам нужно понять как работает `defer`, а не капсом писать. И, пожалуйста, не нужно мне писать, что де Вам не метод нужен, а функция.

Answer (score 0):

А я не понял, почему вариант с `defer` не подойдет:

```
func runningtime(s string) (string, time.Time) {
    log.Println("Start: ", s)
    return s, time.Now()
}

func track(s string, startTime time.Time) {
    endTime := time.Now()
    log.Println("End:   ", s, "took", endTime.Sub(startTime))
}

func execute() {
    defer track(runningtime("execute"))
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}

func main() {
    execute()
}
```

В этом случае, в каждую функцию, время выполнения котрой интересует нужно будет добавить одну строку.

Comment: Опять последнее предложение моего вопроса никто не увидел, уже даже подчеркнул.. Вы выводите все данные на экран через log.Println(), мне же нужна возвращаемая структура, мне не нужно ничего выводить на экран, мне нужно вернуть структуру со всеми данными (время старта, время окончания и т.д), вы же предложили вариант просто выводить на экран данные, без какого либо возврата значения.